# how to echo a forward slash in a php before directory

Tags: php, directory, slash

I have a php code and I want to add a slash (/) before directory but i get error
how can I fix it 
I cannot add slash before **/**login

```
'".DIR . "/login/activate.php'
```

Here is this part of my code

```
$body = "

Thank you for registering at demo site.

To activate account, please follow this link: ".DIR."login/activate.php? x=$id&y=$activasion

Regards Site Admin
";
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you're using DIR instead of 
`__DIR__` Try again with that code and see how it works

Comment: It doesn't work I got instant of "http://" some thing like "link: home/.."

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of putting a slash directly, you could use [DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php).

```
$dir_sep = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

$body = "

Thank you for registering at demo site.

To activate account, please follow this link: ".__DIR__. "login" . $dir_sep . "activate.php? x=$id&y=$activasion

Regards Site Admin
";
```